# Using variable in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I am using a variable in a SQL Server stored procedure and I have a problem with that.

I want to insert data into my table but before insert, I want to check if it already exists, then I will only update the row.

In the query it properly works, but in the stored procedure it does not.

My query is

```
create proc AddPeople
    @Code nvarchar(50),
    @Name nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @PeopleID bigint

    select @PeopleID = id 
    from tbl_People 
    where code = @Code

    if @PeopleID is Null
    begin
        INSERT INTO tbl_People(Code, Name)
        VALUES(@Code, @Name) 

        SELECT @PeopleID = @@IDENTITY
    end
    else
    begin
        UPDATE tbl_People 
        SET Name = @name 
        WHERE id = @PeopleID
    end

    select @PeopleID as id
end
```

In the first "if" @PeopleID always is NULL and the stored procedure inserts the row into the table, but I have code

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: in the code always set @peopleID=NULL and always insert people

Comment: i want 
if i have @Code in my table just update the row

Comment: It looks like it should work to me.  Are you sure you are definitely executing this stored proc?  Like sometimes if you have one accidentally in master or in a schema other than dbo it can become confusing which one is actually running.  Try putting a print statement or something in there so you can be sure this is the one that is executing and print out the value of Code and PeopleID.  Also it would be nice to see the definition of the table you are inserting into

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: A slightly more efficient approach is `UPDATE ... WHERE code = @code; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT ...`

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would happen if `id` had no default value.  Usually, such an `id` would be declared `not null identity()`.  Is this true in your table?

Note:  You don't need to match the `id`.  You can do:

```
if (exists (select 1 from tbl_People where code = @Code))
```

for the conditional logic and then :

```
update tbl_People set Name = @Name where code = @Code;
```

It appears that `Code` is unique on the table, so perhaps the `id` column isn't even necessary.

Comment: i have 170000 row on this table and using the ID in another tables

Comment: and the type of Code column is nvarchar, so searching by this Condition taking time and using cpu

Comment: @mpourbafrani . . . You just need appropriate indexes if your concern is performance.

Comment: thank you for today i use @peopleid=max(id) Instead of of @peopleid=id and its work